# Jasper Java Compile NoClassFound Exception

Tags: jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

Despite the question asked before, I cannot solve the problem by using them. 
I am currently trying to generate pdf file via using the jasper report.However,
I always get an exception related with the jar dependencies. Despite, I add following jars file into my build path,

- jasperreports-6.0.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
- jasperreports-javaflow-6.0.4.jar
- commons.digester3-3.2.jar
- commons-collections4-4.0.jar

program generates me class not found exception either related with  collections.  My main goal is via using jrxml file generate a pdf. I am using iReport 5.6.0 to generate jrxml file. Any help is appreciated. The Stack trace of error is below;

```
Generating PDF...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ReferenceMap
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.<init>(ComponentsEnvironment.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getInstance(ComponentsEnvironment.java:86)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.getSchemaLocations(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.configureParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:117)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1572)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1541)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:263)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:219)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:185)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:575)
    at com.tutorialsdojo.jasper.HelloJasper.main(HelloJasper.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: You need to run commons-collections version 3.2.1.  Likely of [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847455/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-collections-referencemap

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I manage to solve problem and I want to share the answer in order to help the community. The jar dependencies can be gathered via the pom.xml. However, the easy way relies on the iReport (jrxml generated version) installed folder. There is a folder in the location Jaspersoft\iReport-x.x.x\ireport\modules\ext (depends on OS). You can get the following jar files from there;

- jasperreportsXX.jar
- commons-loggingXX.jar
- commons-beanutilsXX.jar
- commons.digesterXX.jar
- commons-collectionsXX.jar
- iTextXX.jar
- jtd-compilerXX.jar
- groovy-allXX.jar

Then all problems  are gone. Hope this helps to other user who meets the problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the jrxml following this tutorial works for me https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_compiling_report_design.htm

Note that all my dependencies are managed by maven