# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

I'm using jdk7, netbeans8, jasperreport5.6.0 and libraries :

```
jasperreport5.6.0.jar, 
commons-logging-1.1.2.jar,
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar,
commons-digester3-3.2.jar,
commons-collections4-4.0.jar,
itext-2.1.0.jar.
```

But after running my application, i got the error, "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap".

How can i resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Java Compile NoClassFound Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30412357/876298) & [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ReferenceMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847455/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-collections-referencemap)

Comment: You can look at the pom.xml and check dependencies

Comment: you have used `org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap` but are using `commons-collections4` - try replacing your usage with `org.apache.commons.collections4.map.ReferenceMap`, or change your import to `commons-collections-3.2.2.jar` (or whatever version of commons-collections you want)